# Upper and Lower bound on scala type

Tags: scala, types, type-bounds

Consider the following hierarchy:

```
class C1
class C2 extends C1
class C3 extends C2
class C4 extends C3
```

I want to write a function that just accepts types `C2` and `C3`. For that I thought of the following:

```
 def f [C >: C3 <: C2](c :C) = 0
```

I'd expect the following behaviour

```
f(new C1)  //doesn't compile, ok
f(new C2)  //compiles, ok
f(new C3)  //compiles, ok
f(new C4)  // !!! Compiles, and it shouldn't
```

The problem is when calling it with `C4`, which I don't want to allow, but the compiler accepts. I understand that `C4 <: C2` is correct and that `C4` can be seen as a `C3`. But when specifying the bound `[C >: C3 <: C2]`, I would expect the compiler to find a `C` that respects both bounds at the same time, not one by one.

Question is : Is there any way to achieve what I want, and if not, is the compiler trying to avoid some inconsistency with this?

**Edit**: from the answers I realized that my presumption is wrong. `C4` always fulfills `C >: C3`, so both bounds are indeed respected. The way to go for my use case is `C3 <:< C`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Statically, yes. It's pretty simple to impose this constraint:

```
def f[C <: C2](c: C)(implicit ev: C3 <:< C) = 0
```

`f(new C4)` wouldn't compile now.

The problem is, it's probably not possible to prohibit the following behaviour at compile time:

```
val c: C3 = new C4
f(c)
```

Here variable `c` has static type `C3`, which passes any kind of typechecking by compiler, but it is actually a `C4` at runtime.

At runtime you can of course check the type using reflection or polymorphism and throw errors or return `Failure(...)` or `None`

Answer (score 5):

I found that explanation from [another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19549048/5020846) very helpful:

> S >: T simply means that if you pass in a type S that is equal to T or its parent, then S will be used. If you pass a type that is sublevel to T then T will be used.

So in your example all, but first should compile.
Following example illustrates the meaning of that:
Let's redefine f:

```
def f[U >: C3 <: C2](c: U) = c
```

and then:

```
 val a2 = f(new C2)
 val a3 = f(new C3) 
 val a4 = f(new C4) 
 List[C2](a2, a3, a4)  //compiles
 List[C3](a3, a4)  //compiles
 List[C4](a4)  //does not cause a4 is C3
```

Hope that helps.