# Why does a method with type parameter bound >: allow subtypes?

Tags: scala, type-bounds

Consider the following simple implementation of a stack in Scala:

```
abstract class Stack[+A] {
  def top: A
  def pop: Stack[A]
}

case object EmptyStack extends Stack[Nothing] {
  def top = error("EmptyStack.top")
  def pop = error("EmptyStack.pop")
}

case class NonEmptyStack[A](elem: A, rest: Stack[A]) extends Stack[A] {
  def top = elem
  def pop = rest
}
```

Now suppose we want to add a `push` method to `Stack`.
The naive attempt

```
abstract class Stack[+A] {
  def push(x: A): Stack[A] = new NonEmptyStack[A](x, this)
  ...
}
```

fails because the `A` in `(x: A)` is a contravariant position.
In [*Scala by Example*](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaByExample.pdf) page 58, the author suggests

```
def push[B >: A](x: B): Stack[B] = new NonEmptyStack[B](x, this)
```

The type bound here means that given a stack of a certain type, we can push objects of an equal or *more general* type to that stack, and the result is a stack of the more general type.

For example,

```
class Fruit
class Apple extends Fruit
class Banana extends Fruit

val apple = new Apple
val banana = new Banana

val stack1 = EmptyStack.push(apple)  // Stack[Apple]
val stack2 = stack1.push(banana)     // Stack[Fruit]
```

I think the point of this choice is that it truly maintains the covariance of `Stack`: if piece of code expects a `Stack[Fruit]` onto which it will push any fruit (banana or apple), then it can still push those fruits onto a `Stack[Apple]`.

Surprisingly, we can also push subtypes:

```
class Honeycrisp extends Apple

val honeycrisp = Honeycrisp
val stack1 = EmptyStack.push(apple)  // Stack[Apple]
val stack2 = stack1.push(honeycrisp) // Stack[Apple], why does this work?
```

Why is this allowed?
Doesn't the type bound `>:` mean that only supertypes should be allowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> def push[B >: A](x: B): Stack[B] = ...
> ```
>
> ...
>
> Why is this allowed? Doesn't the type bound `>:` mean that only supertypes should be allowed?

Only super-types are allowed as `B`, in your example `Apple`. But `x: B` is in a contravariant (input) position, and as such you can always pass a more specific value as an argument. That has nothing to do with the definition of `B`. What you will see however is that the inferred type for `honeycrisp` is `Apple` not `Honeycrisp.`

This is indeed perplexing, and I remember having wondered about this once. But if you go through the implications, it really preserves the type soundness. Of course as a consequence, from the point of view of the body of `push`, `x` is really `Any` without specific capabilities it could count on.

---

Possibly related:

- [Upper and Lower bound on scala type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31609191/upper-and-lower-bound-on-scala-type)

Comment: "But if you go through the consequences, it really preserves the type soundness." Yes, definitely. I came across this because, worried that >: would prevent the ability to pass subtypes, I was trying to figure out how to recover that ability. I'm glad it works the way it does. I was just, as you say, perplexed. Your answer emphasizing the difference between the type parameter and the covariance of the input position clears it all up. Thanks.